# Sending to Exchange 2010 distribution lists

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-server-2012

My Exchange environment is setup with 6 servers, 2 MB/HUB and 4 CAS.  We recently introduced Windows Server 2012 as primary domain controllers into our environment, previously Windows 2003 servers were the primary DC's.  These new servers are also responsible for internal DNS.  Since this change occurred, when an individual sends an email to a distribution list the email gets delayed.  When I look at message in the queue the status shows that it is expanding the list.  Now depending on the size of the list this can take anywhere from 10 minutes to just under an hour.  Any ideas as to why this is occurring and how I can correct this issue?

Thank you

Comment: What does "primary DCs" mean in this context? There's no such thing as a "Primary DC" in Active Directory parlance. How many recipients are in the DL? Are your new DCs also global catalogs?

Comment: meaning we replaced our windows 2003 server domain controllers with server 2012 domain controllers

Comment: Like @MDMarra said.  Make sure you have at least one GC in each ADSS site that holds the CAS' and MB/HUBs.

Comment: All of our DC's are GC's

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like you either don't have a global catalog available in the site your Exchange Servers are in, or you don't have AD Sites and Services configured properly (or some combination of the two). GAL lookups, DL expansion, etc all make heavy use of the GC. If you've recently demoted DCs and the problem arose after you replaced them, I'd guess that your new servers aren't GCs.

Comment: All of our DC's are GC's

Comment: @Stan what about your sites and services configuration? Have you verified that it's correct and that your Exchange servers are querying DCs in their site?